# psmouse serio1: DualPoint TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes

Tags: linux, debian, touchpad, dell-vostro

Recently I have had issue with my DELL Vostro 3750 laptop, the touchpad has eratic behavior.

Looking at the `dmesg` output I can see:

```
[175874.428170] psmouse serio1: DualPoint TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 5 bytes away.
[175874.938670] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
[175879.431915] psmouse serio1: DualPoint TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.
[175879.453182] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
[175889.437902] psmouse serio1: DualPoint TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.
[175889.957166] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
[176624.939847] psmouse serio1: DualPoint TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 4 bytes away.
[176625.454747] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
[176805.063135] psmouse serio1: DualPoint TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.
[176805.573049] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
```

Looking on the web, it seems to happen with [recent linux kernel](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1145954), however I am still using the very same kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux maester 3.14-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.12-1~bpo70+1 (2014-07-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If I turn debugfs on here is what I see:

```
# cat /sys/module/psmouse/parameters/proto
auto
# mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug/
# echo "file drivers/input/mouse/* +p" >  /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

leads to:

```
[ 3484.184294] psmouse serio1: DualPoint TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.
[ 3484.206545] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
[ 3484.657119] psmouse serio1: alps: E6 report: 00 00 64
[ 3484.679989] psmouse serio1: alps: E7 report: 73 02 64
[ 3484.703271] psmouse serio1: alps: EC report: 88 07 9d
[ 3484.724681] psmouse serio1: alps: EC report: 88 07 9d
[ 3484.795169] psmouse serio1: alps: EC report: 88 07 9d
[ 3489.186775] psmouse serio1: DualPoint TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.
[ 3489.209246] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
[ 3489.661888] psmouse serio1: alps: E6 report: 00 00 64
[ 3489.685972] psmouse serio1: alps: E7 report: 73 02 64
[ 3489.711895] psmouse serio1: alps: EC report: 88 07 9d
[ 3489.732625] psmouse serio1: alps: EC report: 88 07 9d
[ 3489.781987] psmouse serio1: alps: EC report: 88 07 9d
[ 3859.439899] psmouse serio1: DualPoint TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.
[ 3859.461770] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
[ 3859.910943] psmouse serio1: alps: E6 report: 00 00 64
[ 3859.935221] psmouse serio1: alps: E7 report: 73 02 64
[ 3859.960135] psmouse serio1: alps: EC report: 88 07 9d
[ 3859.982875] psmouse serio1: alps: EC report: 88 07 9d
[ 3860.032681] psmouse serio1: alps: EC report: 88 07 9d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my system to a debian/jessie system and everything was also non-working.

After playing with `i8k` module, I realized that `i8kmon` was running on scheduled intervals. I decided to [stop it](https://bugs.debian.org/785601#15) and also [manually removing](https://bugs.debian.org/785601#30) the `i8k` module. For some reason blacklist was not enough:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/i8k-blacklist.conf
# https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=732242
blacklist i8k
```

The touchpad now behaves nicely, no issue with the keyboard anymore. And even the fan is turning at correct speed (it used to start/stop for no reason).